# LeetCode Arranging Coins Recursive Solution Leads To StackOverflowError?

Tags: c#, recursion, runtime-error

Here is the question: **You have a total of n coins that you want to form in a staircase shape, where every k-th row must have exactly k coins.Given n, find the total number of full staircase rows that can be formed. n is a non-negative integer and fits within the range of a 32-bit signed integer.**

This is my Recursive Solution Below.

```
public class Solution {

    public int Solver(int n, int m) {
        if(n - m < m || n == 0) {
            return m;
        }
        m++;
        return Solver(n - m, m);
    }
    public int ArrangeCoins(int n) {
        return Solver(n, 0);
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Runtime Error Message:
Unhandled Exception:
StackOverflowException
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x5c441d, fault addr: 0x7fff33c3b0b8
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x7f7a0fef6bbc, fault addr: 0x7fff33c3af68

Unhandled Exception:
StackOverflowException
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x5681fc, fault addr: 0x7fff33c3bff8
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x5c441d, fault addr: 0x7fff33c3a478
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x7f7a0fef6bbc, fault addr: 0x7fff33c39fe8
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x4b1567, fault addr: 0x7fff33c3bcc0
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x5c441d, fault addr: 0x7fff33c39698
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Nested exception detected.
Original Exception: at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.MonoIO.Close (intptr,System.IO.MonoIOError&) [0x00026] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0
at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose (bool) [0x00037] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0
at System.IO.Stream.Close () [0x00002] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose (bool) [0x00045] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0
at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose () [0x00002] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0
at __Driver__.Main (string[]) [0x00066] in __Driver__.cs:41

Nested exception:at string.FillStringChecked (string,int,string) [0x00006] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0
at string.Concat (string,string,string) [0x00049] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0
at System.Exception.ToString (bool,bool) [0x0002e] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0
at System.Exception.ToString () [0x00003] in <2e7c1c96edae44d496118948ca617c11>:0

Last executed input: 1957747793
```

I know that this solution works, as I can run it on my any other IDE and it works for the specific input that this errors out on. What exactly did I do wrong?

Here is proof that it works for that input: http://rextester.com/CNJ29548

I can solve this quicker using just math, but I wanted to improve my recursion skills and this seemed like a perfect problem to do that on. Help?

Comment: Presumably it's executed in an environment with less stack available, or where tail recursion isn't implemented when it might be on your machine. Given the simple nature of the recursion here, it shouldn't be hard to change it to an iterative solution.

Comment: Thank you. I figured I could solve it in an iterative way, I just wanted to practice my skills with recursion for interviewing questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I know that this solution works". I'm afraid you may have used the [programmer's proof](https://xavierleroy.org/stuff/prime-numbers.html) for that, since the result for "6" is "2"; and "10" and 11" return "3". Try this...

```
    public int Solver(int coinsRemaining, int coinsOnNextRow)
    {
        if (coinsRemaining >= coinsOnNextRow)
        {
            return Solver(coinsRemaining - coinsOnNextRow, coinsOnNextRow + 1);
        }

        return coinsOnNextRow - 1;
    }
    public int ArrangeCoins(int n)
    {
        return Solver(n, 1);
    }
```

Still gets a stack overflow for that value, but at least it was on its way to the right answer :)

I think the issue is the use of the stack because you're using recursion. There's no need for recursion here... just use a while loop (this works with your desired input, giving 62573 as the answer, is that right?):

```
    public int ArrangeCoins(int coinsRemaining)
    {
        int coinsOnNextRow = 1;
        while (coinsRemaining >= coinsOnNextRow)
        {
            coinsRemaining -= coinsOnNextRow;
            coinsOnNextRow++;
        }

        return coinsOnNextRow - 1;
    }
```

Comment: Oops! I know why too. I incremented the m variable in the wrong locations, so I think it was always 1 less than it should have been going into the recursive call! Thank you for that!

Comment: Yeah, I know recursion isn't necessary I can easily solve it in an iterative fashion, I just wanted to practice recursion, and I figured that this would be a nice problem to practice it with. 

And yeah, you are correct, 62753 is the answer, I was able to get it to, but Stack Overflowed. So I guess leetcode doesn't want a recursive solution to this problem. Lol. Thank you for your help!